# Setting TextView visible(or gone) in ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, visible

I am tying to set a textview inside my ListView visible depending on another variable. But when I try

```
TextView sdate;
TextView stime;
sdate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
stime= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
```

It seems like it can't find the 2 in the layout?

From what I gather, there needs to be something in front of the findViewbyId() but I'm not sure on what. The items layout in the list is done by list_item.xml. The code that is handling all this is:

```
                ListAdapter adapter;
                if(add.equals("Event")){
                    stime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllSpotsActivity.this, spotsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME, "sdistance","dateof","timeof" }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.distance, R.id.date, R.id.time});
                }else{
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllSpotsActivity.this, spotsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, "sdistance" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.distance });
                }
```

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background" 
>


<!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="12dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2:
I've also tried using lv.findViewById() because lv=getListView(); But that did not work either.

Comment: post your xml where you define the textview.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call `findViewById()` on each row's view. For example, if you are calling that method from the `getView()` method of your adapter, you should use `convertView.findViewById`.

Comment: Yeah, in the onCreate() i have lv = getView();, but when I tried covertView it just underlines it asking to define it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have anything more than a simple TextView as the layout for each item in a ListView, what you'll need to do is create a custom adapter that extends [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). Inside of the getView() method of your custom adapter, you will have access to your custom xml layout (one of the arguments to the [constructor of the ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) is the resource ID of the layout file you want to have for each item in the list [e.g., R.layout.your_custom_list_item]). From inside of that method, you will have access to either a new or recycled view, which you can inflate your custom layout within.

The [LayoutInflater.inflate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29) method you call from inside the getView() method will return you a view that you can call findViewById() on to get access to all the views in your custom layout that you want to interact with. It's there that you can make your views visible or invisible based on the data you pass into the adapter (the third argument to the adapter's constructor is either a list or an adapter with the data you want to use to populate the views). I strongly recommend you watch the [I/O video on ListViews](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for a more complete explanation. I've also included some sample code for a custom adapter below.

```
public class BookingSearchResultsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchResult> {

private static final String TAG = BookingSearchResultsAdapter.class.getName();

private int mLayoutResourceId;  
private Context mContext;
private List<SearchResult> mResults = null;

public BookingSearchResultsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SearchResult> results) {
    super(context, resource, results);

    mContext = context;
    mLayoutResourceId = resource;
    mResults = results;
}

/**
 * @return A view to display search result
 */
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        SearchResultVendorViewHolder holder = null;

        // if there is no recycled view available
        if(row == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No recyclable custom view found. New view created.");
        // get a new search result view
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

            // store all static view information in a holder
            holder = new SearchResultVendorViewHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.search_result_establishment_icon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.search_result_establishment_name);
            holder.txtDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.search_result_establishment_description);

            // attach the holder to the view so that it can be recycled
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "View recycled");
        // get the recycled view (stored in tag)
            holder = (SearchResultVendorViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        // initialize data in custom search result view
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) mResults.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(result.getEstablishmentName());
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(result.getImageId());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(result.getDescription());
        Log.d(TAG, "Custom search view data initialized");
        return row;
    }


    static class SearchResultVendorViewHolder {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDescription;
    }
}
```